# Intercept HTML form POST data

Tags: html, forms, security

If a person submits a very basic HTML contact form on a website (filling in subject, description and email input fields), is it possible for another person to intercept or "grab" the POSTed data, in particular the email address. In this scenario i do not care about the client-side where there could always be security vulnerabilities, for example someone listening in on the client's network traffic, clickjacking, etc.

Let me know if the question is too broad or confusing and i need to explain it more in detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any network sniffer then it's possible to intercept or listen to the traffic between the client and the website. This is possible if the 'sniffer' is in the same network.
To prevent sniffing, the connection between client and website must be established by an HTTPS connection.

HTTPS provides an encrypted connection so only the client and server can decrypt the data. If someone would intercept this connection, then they only get to see encrypted data like this:

[image]